# How to infer type from property of items of Array-property

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have a type like this:

```
type Person = {
    name: string;
    relatives: Array<Person>;
    favoriteRelative: string;
}
```

But I want to enforce `favoriteRelative` to be a `name` from any Person in `relatives`.

I tried this, but got only `string` instead of the wanted list of strings (probably due to the names not being considered a const-Array):

```
type Person<R extends Array<Person>> = {
    name: string;
    relatives: R;
    favoriteRelative: R[number]['name'];
}
```

I tried the `infer` keyword like this, but got an error :

```
type Person<T extends Array<Person>> = T extends infer R ? {
    name: string;
    relatives: R;
    favoriteRelative: R[number]['name']; // Type  number  cannot be used to index type  R
} : never
```

I don't get the answer either out of the Typescript docs or other closely related SO threads.

Comment: Would it not make more sense to have `favoriteRelative: Person` to keep the type hierarchy? You'd still have to use generics, but then you could do `T extends Array<Person>` where T is the relative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Dynamic* type inference can only be done via functions

```
type Person<F extends string = string> = {
    name: string;
    relatives: ReadonlyArray<Person>;
    favoriteRelative: F;
}

type OneOf<T> = T extends ReadonlyArray<infer E> ? E : never
type Fallback<T, F> = [T] extends [never] ? F : T

function Person<
  const P extends Person<R>,
  R extends string = Fallback<OneOf<P['relatives']>['name'], string>
>(person: P): P {
  return person
}
```

[Typescript playground with examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOwDwDEoQB7AlQBNEpFh4BLVAcygF4yLqaA%20BqAbwCgo%20pUAQwC2EAFxMqtANy9%208CABtBwSgDcIiCQCUIgomkUgAgvHiCQ6OEjStZ-KADNBa5FQK7lqjRMyyAvtzcoJBQAPKoEGGO6AAq7IyxOPiEJFC6%20oYmZhbo1I4IUACi7AD8xVASkRrwweDQmIKKigBGggDGANZxADRQmAlQANqxALrJBMSkQ9UI4%20XYErFBjgCuqO2qaLAIKBjtaOSwE6mk1nvo2qx92idTkiwcjc1tXegRUTEwQwDkCl7qTQ-UasX5CUTAvrkKRsVgACkgNlQEhgAEoUVw5ApgKt4KgoIi9txAkEDqgjk0WghgBxzmg4Tw%20ODxFAfsZWtSfj0sUoVICtMNRty%20M5XO4IJ4%20T5WT9iaigiFoElGIrkI4oJTqQA6Zmkw40gBWyEQEDAAAtabt6YyBCIWT8AFLG01mrk8gEaAVDTXwYBCuSityUDy87z29lU32y-zy7hkimKPCWpEMuTMiRsxO4N18f5SzQSb0c319I0m83%20kUuIMhj32zAIITEZDR1FAA)